# How to get all methods of class in Apex

Tags: apex

I want to get all methods of a class to list them on visualforce page. Is there any inbuilt function to get them like Java. If no, then how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Tooling API for that. There is an [`ApexClassMember`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexclassmember.htm) class for accessing an Apex class and a [`SymbolTable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/sforce_api_objects_symboltable.htm) field that represents all user-defined tokens in the Body of the class, like:

- constructors
- interfaces
- methods
- variables

Comment: @mastOr can you please share sample query ,
I tried :
Select FullName, SymbolTable from ApexClassMember 
and getting 0 Rows

Comment: Broken link on the ApexClassMember